# How to use Wildcard URLs in Kentico 9?

Tags: url, wildcard, kentico

I tried to use wildcard URLs in my project and it does not work for me. I set page URL to `/path/to/page/{UserId}` (I also tried `UserName` and `NinjaMaster` wildcard name to prevent naming conflicts) but I wasn't able access this variable in template or web part (I tried Repeater web part only).

In my HTML template I tried `{% UserId #%}`, `{% UserName #%}` and `{% NinjaMaster #%}` to write passed value, but nothing happen. I tried URLs like `/path/to/page/12345`, `/path/to/page/?UserId=12345`, `/path/to/page/?userid=12345` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wildcard name in the URL is actually a query string.

When visiting `/path/to/page/5` (and the wildcard URL being `/path/to/page/{UserId}`), the URL is rewritten to something along the lines of `/CMSPages/PortalTemplate.aspx?aliasPath=/actual/path/to/page&UserId=5`

To access the query string value in a macro, use `{% QueryString.UserId %}`

Answer (score 1):

Read about [query string macros](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Macro+syntax).
You can use two types of syntax: `{? UserId ?}` or `{% QueryString.UserId %}`

Answer (score 0):

I am quoting straight from [Kentico's documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Macro+syntax)

To load the values of query string parameters from the URL, use macros in format:

`{? parameter ?}`

Query string macros support all K# syntax. The names of all available query string parameters automatically work as variables that store the value of the corresponding parameter.

For example, on pages with URLs like /Home.aspx?nodeid=10, `{? nodeid ?}` resolves into 10.

Alternatively, you can get the values of query string parameters inside standard macros:

`{% QueryString.parameter %}`